# Handling routes with Angular and Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app where I am trying to remove the hashbang ( `!` and `#`) prefixes for my routes, but still have people be able to use bookmarked routes.  For the most part I have been able to get it work with `html5Mode` set to `true`, but there are a few cases where it is not working.  Here is how I have my server configured:

```
var router = require('./router')(app);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root:'../client/app/'});
});
```

`router` in this case looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Products = require('../../database').Products;

router.get('/:flavor', function (req, res) {
  var flavor = req.params.flavor;
  Products.findOne({flavor:flavor}, function (err, product) {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    res.json(product);
  });
```

Getting the `flavor` routes, is one case where this setup does not work.  If someone directly types into the browse, `mysite.com/lemon` they receive the `JSON` data back, only (no template or anything).  Normally this is used by the angular app, (which would typically make the request to `/lemon` and implement it into the template). However, if I move the `router` below the `app.get('*')`, then any request made by Angular for the data is returned with the entire `index.html` page. How can I make it so that a direct request by the browser for a route that normally returns `JSON` sends the index file?

Comment: You need to return index always if it is not API request.

Comment: `router.get('/', function (req, res) {/*return index*/});`

Comment: or `router.get('/api/:flavor', function (req, res) {/*your Products code*/});`

Comment: Your last suggestion is what I used.